# Replace values in a list if condition is true

Tags: python

how can I replace the numbers that are greater than 9 by their sum of digits?

right now the list multipliedlist =

```
[1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 16, 2]
```

I need to change it to (ex, num 12 and num 16 replaced to (3) and (7) )

```
[1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 3, 7, 7, 2]
```

I can use `sum(map(int, str(number)))` to add the digits but how can i change the values in the same list by their index?

```
def check_id_valid(id_number):
    updatedid = map(int, str(id_number))
    multipliedlist = [i * 1 if j % 2 == 0 else i * 2 for j, i in enumerate(updatedid)]

    # for index, number in enumerate(multipliedlist):
    #     if multipliedlist[index] > 9:
    #         multipliedlist[index] = sum(map(int, str(number)))
    #     else:
    #         multipliedlist[index] == number #statement has no effect error.

print(check_id_valid(123456782))
```

New to python sorry if this is not explained as it's supposed to be

I appreciate any help,Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
data = [1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 16, 2]
print([sum(map(int, str(i))) if i > 9 else i for i in data])
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 3, 7, 7, 2]
```

Comment: Thank this is what I needed and it works but,what's the correct way to update my current list ? can i do?


      multipliedlist = [i * 1 if j % 2 == 0 else i * 2 for j, i in enumerate(updatedid)]


      multipliedlist = ([sum(map(int, str(i))) if i > 9 else i for i in multipliedlist])

Answer (score 3):

Break your task into the constituent parts, namely

- replacing a number with the sum of its digits
- doing that for a list of numbers.

```
def sum_digits(number):
    # Convert the number into a string (10 -> "10"),
    # iterate over its characters to convert each of them
    # back to an integer, then use the `sum()` builtin for
    # summing.
    return sum(int(digit_char) for digit_char in str(number))

def sum_all_digits(numbers):
    return [sum_digits(number) for number in numbers]

print(sum_all_digits([1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 16, 2]))
```

outputs the expected

```
[1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 3, 7, 7, 2]
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't explain clearly, but what I meant is to change the values in the list (multipliedlist)

Answer (score 1):

To change values by index you can use enumerate() function:

```
def sum_digits(n):
    r = 0
    while n:
        r, n = r + n % 10, n // 10
    return r


multipliedlist = [1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 16, 2]


for i, n in enumerate(multipliedlist):
    multipliedlist[i] = sum_digits(multipliedlist[i])

print(multipliedlist)
```

[1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 3, 7, 7, 2]